# Allocate memory for flexible array in structure

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, calloc, flexible-array-member

I am trying to allocate memory for a structure using a flexarray. I received it this way and I have to implement it like this.

The structure looks like:

```
struct _XPM {

    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned char cpp;
    unsigned int ncolors;
    Color *colta;
    unsigned int *data[];
}; //it's a typedef to XPM in the headder file
```

I have a function that initiates the structure. It is there where I have the problem. I really don't know: do I have to use malloc to allocate memory for the structure and that's it, or do I need to allocate memory to `*data[]` like a pointer to an array?

```
void initXPM(XPM *imagine,
        unsigned int width,
        unsigned int height,
        unsigned char cpp,
        unsigned int ncolors) {

imagine = ( XPM* ) malloc ( sizeof ( XPM ) + sizeof ( unsigned int* ) * width * height );
/* I think I need to allocate sizeof(unsigned int) *width * height because 
I have to work with an array of pixels  */ 

    if(!imagine) {
        perror( "Error allocating resources for XPM structure" );
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Then do I have to write the following code or not?

```
imagine -> data = ( unsigned int* ) calloc( width, sizeof( unsigned int ) );
    if( !imagine->data ) {
        perror( "Error allocating resources for XPM data width" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for( i = 0; i < width; i++ ) {
        imagine -> data[i] = (unsigned int*) calloc ( height, sizeof(unsigned int) );
        if( !imagine -> data[i] ) {
            perror( "Error allocating resources for XPM data height" );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough. If not, I can try to explain it again.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long do you want `imagine->data` to be? It seems that you want it to be `width` elements long, so do this:

```
imagine = ( XPM* ) malloc ( sizeof ( XPM ) + sizeof ( unsigned int* ) * width);
```

Also, the cast `(XPM*)` is unnecessary in C, but that's not strictly important. It won't stop your code working.

This is unnecessary and wrong:

```
imagine -> data = ( unsigned int* ) calloc( width, sizeof( unsigned int ) );
if( !imagine->data ) {
    perror( "Error allocating resources for XPM data width" );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You already allocated the memory for `imagine->data` at the same time as `imagine` itself. If you had declared `unsigned int **data;` instead of `unsigned int *data[];`, this would be correct. If you had chosen that way, you would need to allocate only `sizeof(XPM)` bytes for `imagine`, instead of `sizeof(XPM) + sizeof(unsigned int*)*width`, because the array `imagine->data` would be stored separately from the structure `imagine`.

The rest of your code, which allocates an array for each row of pixels, is fine.

Comment: You shouldn't actually be able to do `imagine->data = ...` because `imagine->data` is an array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)
I also thought of using **data, but this is the way I have received the code, so I must use it this way unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

You should be ok by simply doing something like:

```
XPM *initXPM(unsigned int width,
             unsigned int height,
             unsigned char cpp,
             unsigned int ncolors) {

    XPM *imagine = ( XPM* ) malloc ( sizeof ( XPM ) );
    imagine->data = ( unsigned int *) malloc ( sizeof ( unsigned int ) * width * height);

    if(!imagine) {
        perror( "Error allocating resources for XPM structure" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ...

    return imagine;
}
```

There is no need to execute your second set of statements, as the allocation for the array of 'unsigned int' data is  already being allocated in the first set.

Comment: ah yes that's correct, I was assuming he wanted to have one array of uints covering width+height instead of an array of arrays.